# Calling an helper with linq expression capabilities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to transform my

```
<input type="file" id="image" name="image">
```

with something like

```
@Html.UploadFor(model => model.Image)
```

Something more MVC friendly...

I know that I have to create a helper for that with Linq Expression capabilities.

How this can be done?

**EDIT**

Here is one solution:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString UploadFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("input");
        builder.MergeAttribute("type", "file");
        builder.MergeAttribute("id", HtmlExtensions.IdFor(helper, expression));
        builder.MergeAttribute("name", HtmlExtensions.NameFor(helper, expression));
        return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static string NameFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
    }

    public static string IdFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName(NameFor(htmlHelper, expression));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this reference/tutorial for creating custom HTML Helpers: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

```
public static MvcHtmlString UploadFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) 
{ 
    // generate your HTML 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I know the basic Html Helpers but here I would like to use the Linq expressions in it (model => model.Image). This is much more difficult for me.

Comment: @Bronzato I have edited my post to include a structure that you'll have for your extension method to take into consideration Linq expressions.  You'll have a strongly types `HtmlHelper` and utilize the strongly-typed `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited my question to include a solution.